# Dynamics - Find the height of the bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, calculus

[image: Question]

Working :

$$
\text{Let the origin be where the paintbrush hits the ground}
$$
$$
\text{Let time = 0 when the paintbrush is dropped}
$$
$$
\text{For the car:}
$$
$$
v_c(t)=v
$$
$$
d_c(t)=vt+c, v(0)=-20
$$
$$
d_c(t)=vt -20
$$
$$
d_c(t_0)=0 \text{, the point at which the car passes underneath the paintbrush}
$$
$$
d_c(t_1)=10 \text{, the point at which the paintbrush hits the ground}
$$
$$
d_c(t_0)=0
$$
$$
0=vt-20
$$
$$
t=\frac{20}v
$$
$$
\text{For the paintbrush:}
$$
$$
a_p(t)=-9.8
$$
$$
v_p(t)=-9.8t
$$
$$
d_p(t)=-4.9t^2+c
$$
$$
d_p(t_0)=5\text{, the point at which the car passes underneath the paintbrush}
$$
$$
d_p(t_1)=0\text{, the point at which the paintbrush hits the ground}
$$

Since the velocity is constant I know $\frac23t_0=t_1$ but I'm unsure how to use this, any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your **specific** question about **mathematics** as an area of study? It *seems* to me like you just need help on your physics homework, which is more appropriate for Physics SE (and, at any rate, not really what the SE network is designed for).

Comment: Are you familiar with Stack Exchange’s “Be Nice” policy?

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: Please do not post questions that just use screenshots of a textbook problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of considering the height above the bridge, simply consider the distance the brush falls.  Since it starts from rest with constant acceleration, distance is proportional to time squared.  For the car, time is proportional to distance.  So, if $h$ is the height of the bridge then
$$\frac{h-5}{h}=\Bigl(\frac{20}{20+10}\Bigr)^2$$
which gives $h=9$.